# fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git on rake task on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, rake

Now, first let me say that this is not actually fatal. It continues to go and do the task. However, I'm worried that it may be a symptom of something else... and "fatal" looks ... bad...

I get this message whenever I run a rake task on Heroku. Obviously the rake task is part of a git repo, because otherwise I couldn't push the ruby app to Heroku in the first place...

However, when I heroku run bash, and do an ls -a, sure enough, there is no .git. There is a .gitignore and .gitattributes, but no .git. The original that I'm pushing to heroku DOES have a .git/

Is this a heroku setting thing? or a git thing? or just a thing I'll have to live with?